# ESP home using Arduino library

Tags: c++, arduino-c++, esphome

I am about to write a custom ESPHome component. I don't have much experience with C language and I am facing some troubles using external library.

For demonstration, I prepared a simple component class..

```
class Test: public Component {

public:
    auto t = timer_create_default();

    void setup() override {
        ESP_LOGD("TEST", "Test setup called!");
        t.every(1000, TestLog);
    }
    
    void loop() override {
        ESP_LOGD("TEST", "Test loop called!");
        t.tick();
    }
    
    bool TestLog(void *) {
        ESP_LOGD("TEST", "TestLOG!");
        return true;
    }
}
```

With this, I receive:

> In file included from src\main.cpp:32:0: src\Test.h:7:35: error:
> non-static data member declared 'auto'
> auto t = timer_create_default();

I took it from some example where they did not have the class, but I can't find out, how to use it.

The library is:

https://github.com/contrem/arduino-timer/

I can still rewrite it without this timer completely and handle it only in the loop function, but I would like to understand what I am doing wrong.

If I change the return type to Timer<> I got another error:

> src\Test.h: In member function 'virtual void Test::setup()':
> src\Test.h:11:24: error: no matching function for call to
> 'Timer<>::every(int, )'
> t.every(1000, TestLog);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `auto` to declare non-`static` member variables so you need to replace `auto` with the type returned by `timer_create_default()`.

If you are not sure what type it returns, you can simply use `decltype` in the declaration:

```cpp
decltype(timer_create_default()) t = timer_create_default();
```

If I read the code in the repo correctly, the returned type is `Timer<>`, so this should also work:

```cpp
Timer<> t = timer_create_default();
```

or simply:

```cpp
Timer<> t;
```

Also: The function pointer passed to `t.every()` should be a `bool (*)(void*)` but `TestLog` is a non-`static` member function and the pointer type is `bool (Test::*)(void*)` - You can fix that by making `TestLog` `static`:

```cpp
class Test: public Component {
public:
    // ...

    static bool TestLog(void *) {
        ESP_LOGD("TEST", "TestLOG!");
        return true;
    }
};
```

If you want to get the `Test` instance in the `TestLog` callback, make the `Timer`

```cpp
Timer<TIMER_MAX_TASKS, millis, Test*> t;
```

and change `TestLog`:

```cpp
class Test: public Component {
public:
    // ...

    static bool TestLog(Test* t) {
        ESP_LOGD("TEST", "TestLOG!");
        return true;
    }
};
```

and in `setup()`:

```cpp
t.every(1000, TestLog, this);
```

You'll now get a pointer to the `Test` instance in the `TestLog` callback and you can use this to call a non-`static` member function in `Test`.

Full example:

```cpp
class Test : public Component {
public:
    Timer<TIMER_MAX_TASKS, millis, Test*> t;

    void setup() override {
        ESP_LOGD("TEST", "Test setup called!");
        // call the static member function every second:
        t.every(1000, TestLogProxy, this);
    }
    
    void loop() override {
        ESP_LOGD("TEST", "Test loop called!");
        t.tick();
    }

    bool TestLog() {
        ESP_LOGD("TEST", "TestLOG!");
        return true;
    }
    
    static bool TestLogProxy(Test* t) {
        // forward the callback call to the non-static member function:
        return t->TestLog();
    }
};
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot to write that I tried that already... but I got another error message:          
src\Test.h: In member function 'virtual void Test::setup()':
src\Test.h:11:24: error: no matching function for call to 'Timer<>::every(int, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
   t.every(1000, TestLog);

Comment: @OndrejHavlicek That's unrelated to the problem you've asked a question about. The solution to the problem you asked about is in my answer. It seems you call `t.every(1000, TestLog);` in `setup()` but `every` does not have an overload accepting those parameters.

Comment: @OndrejHavlicek Is `TestLog` a `handler_t` instance?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support ;) But I need somehow to get this code working in general. Do you see why the method TestLog is not visible/usable? Or do You think I should create a new question?

Comment: Ups, IDK, how to check if it is?

Comment: @OndrejHavlicek I updated the answer to take care of that. When it comes to making the code work in general: Stackoverflow isn't the place to ask for collaborations on projects. You here should ask one specific question, [accept answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that solves the problem and then move on. If you have more questions, you can ask them one at a time as your project evolves.